# Foreign words break spellchecking

Tags: software, language, microsoft-word

I am writing a text with a lot of foreign words, and MS Word complained that there were too many ‘errors’ and stopped checking spelling. Is there a way to force spellchecking? (Short of creating a separate style, which I do for entire sentences but which would be impractical for isolated words.) I have foreign words in italics; letting Word know that italics are off-limit would work.

Answer (score 4):

## You need to install a foreign dictionary

> [Microsoft Word can use multiple custom dictionaries](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322198/how-to-add-a-custom-dictionary-in-word) to check the
>   spelling of your documents. A custom dictionary allows you to
>   supplement the main dictionary with additional words, such as names,
>   specialized technical terms, foreign words or alternative spelling of
>   some words.

You can [buy foreign dictionaries in the Office Store](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/install-a-dictionary-77be8dd8-23a0-4e8b-a321-a6f40c9610a5).

Or find them online.

But [many languages are built in](https://itstillworks.com/add-french-dictionary-microsoft-word-5876058.html) and you just have to choose them from an internal menu.

Comment: +1 You could also add words to the current dictionary as you go (after you check that they are correctly spelled), or right-click and ignore, to ignore them for good.

Comment: @NofP which works well if there only 20-50 words, not if there are hundreds...

Comment: @NofP It is a plausible tactic for common words, but should foreign words be added to the dictionary?

Comment: @Cyn Unfortunately, this will not work with transliterations of Japanese words (which are not found in Japanese dictionaries).

Comment: @MathieuBouville I may be wrong but if you don't want to contaminate your everyday dictionary, you should be able to add them to a custom dictionary and use it for that particular project. Hence Cyn suggestion of using custom dictionaries is still a good idea.

Comment: Good points @MathieuBouville, if your language is in a non-Roman alphabet, adding them one word at a time to your primary dictionary isn't going to work well (if at all) even if there's just a few.  Installing a custom dictionary is the way to go.

Comment: But if you're using transliterations, I'm sure there are going to exist custom dictionaries for that.  But you may have to purchase one vs just finding it.

Comment: @MathieuBouville So...I stand by my answer, that installing a foreign dictionary from inside Word is the way to solve this problem.  It's the "correct" answer.  And it works most of the time. But...I just spent about an hour trying to find a Romaji spellchecker with zero luck.  I'm shocked but it seems it doesn't exist.  There are plenty of great Japanese language tools and Japanese-English (and E-J) dictionaries that support Romaji, but no spellcheckers.  This post sums it up: https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-good-spellcheckers-for-people-who-are-still-learning-and-supports-Romaji-and-Kana